# Find all IPs on an HTML Page

Tags: python, regex, screen-scraping, extract

I want to get an HTML page with python and then print out all the IPs from it. 
I will define an IP as the following:

**x**.**x**.**x**.**x**:**y**

Where:
x = a number between 0 and 256.
y = a number with < 7 digits.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to clarify this a bit. It's not clear what you're trying to do. 

What do you mean when you say "get an HTML page with python and then print out all the IPs from it?"

Comment: I believe he means to extract IP addresses from the HTML.

Comment: I want to download a webpage and print out all strings with the format x.x.x.x:y as defined. Please clarify your question because I dont understand what you dont understand about my question.

Comment: Do you mean parse out all URLs from an HTML page and create the list of IP addresses that those URLs refer to (that is, the domain that the URL comes from)?

Comment: Or maybe you're implying that these particular HTML pages will explicitly list IP addresses on them?

Comment: @Ross: He wants to extract all literal IPv4 addresses (with what looks to be port specifications) that appear in the HTML; I'm guessing it's some sort of screen-scraping of a published list.

Comment: @das please look at my new and improved code that has been tested to work.

Comment: y seems to be a port number and port numbers are not limited to 7 digits, but to 2^16

also 192.168.1.1:003 won't suit you: the port number has 3 digits but it normally can't start with zeros

I'd rather scan for patterns like (pseudolanguage):

[digits].[digits].[digits].[digits]:[digits]

then make sure the leading char in each group is not '0', then convert each group into an integer and compare it against the boundaries

Answer (score 3):

> Right. The only part I cant do is the regular expression one. – das 9 mins ago If someone shows me that, I will be fine. – das 8 mins ago

```
import re

ip = re.compile(r"\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?):\d{1,6}\b")
junk = " 1.1.1.1:123 2.2.2.2:321 312.123.1.12:123 "
print ip.findall(junk)

# outputs ['1.1.1.1:123', '2.2.2.2:321']
```

Here is a complete example:

```
import re, urllib2

f = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.samair.ru/proxy/ip-address-01.htm")
junk = f.read()

ip = re.compile(r"\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?):\d{1,6}\b")
print ip.findall(junk)

# ['114.30.47.10:80', '118.228.148.83:80', '119.70.40.101:8080', '12.47.164.114:8888', '121.
# 17.161.114:3128', '122.152.183.103:80', '122.224.171.91:3128', '123.234.32.27:8080', '124.
# 107.85.115:80', '124.247.222.66:6588', '125.76.228.201:808', '128.112.139.75:3128', '128.2
# 08.004.197:3128', '128.233.252.11:3124', '128.233.252.12:3124']
```

Comment: In [9]: ip.search("255x255x255x255:12")
Out[9]: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x103c650>

Comment: @ llimllib: 
>>> ip.match("255x255x255x255:12")
>>>

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach would be:

- Use [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to download the contents of the page
- Use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) to extract IPv4-like addresses
- Validate each match according to the numeric constraints on each octet
- Print out the list of matches

Please provide a clearer indication of what specific part you are having trouble with, along with evidence to show what it is you've tried thus far.

Comment: Right. The only part I cant do is the regular expression one.

Answer (score 1):

Not to turn this into a who's-a-better-regex-author-war but...

```
(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\:\d{1,6}
```

Comment: You can't have IPs with zeroes?

Comment: Needs to be coupled with something to constrain the acceptable octet values.

Comment: "\d{1,3}" simply means 1-3 digits. A couple already submitted more "correct" regexes already, so it's a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
re.compile("\d?\d?\d.\d?\d?\d.\d?\d?\d.\d?\d?\d:\d+").findall(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
```

Comment: Needs to be coupled with something to constrain the acceptable octet values.

Answer (score 0):

**[In action](http://regexr.com?3202m)**:

```
\b(?:                # A.B.C in A.B.C.D:port
    (?:
       25[0-5]
    |  2[0-4][0-9]
    |  1[0-9][0-9]
    |  [1-9]?[0-9]
    )\.
  ){3}
  (?:                # D in A.B.C.D:port
    25[0-5]
  | 2[0-4][0-9]
  | 1[0-9][0-9]
  | [1-9]?[0-9]
  )
  :[1-9]\d{0,5}     # port number any number in (0,999999]
\b
```